# what is meaning partial resynchronization of redis?

Tags: redis

Starting with Redis 2.8,redis add a function named "Partial resynchronization".I read [this](http://redis.io/topics/replication) official document,but i don't understand.who can help me?

Answer (score 5):

It is about master-slave replication.

The normal behavior of a Redis slave (slave of command, or configuration) is to connect to the master, ask the master to accumulate master-slave traffic, request a complete dump on filesystem to the master, download this dump on the slave, load the dump, and finally play the accumulated traffic until the slave catches up with the master.

This mechanism is quite robust but not very efficient to cover transient connection drops between the slave and the master. If the master-slave link is down for a couple of seconds, the slave will request a full resynchronization (involving a dump, etc ...), even if only a few commands have been missed.

Starting with 2.8, Redis includes a partial replication mechanism so a slave can reconnect to the master, and if some conditions are met (like a transient connection drop), asks the master to resynchronize without having to dump the whole memory instance.

In order to support this feature, the master has to buffer and keep a backlog of commands, so they can be served to the slaves at any time if needed. If the slave is too late behind the master, the backlog may not contain anymore the required data. In that case, a normal full synchronization is done, as in previous versions.

Comment: I want konw that when a few commands have been missed if the master-slave link is down for a couple of seconds and the slave will request a full resynchronization.I mean that you can take examples。。

Comment: I mean i don't find that a few commands have been missed when Master and slave are able to continue the replication after master-slave link is down for a couple of seconds.

Comment: From the user point of view, no command will be missing. Pre-2-8 versions will perdorm a full resynchronization, 2-8 or better will do partial synchronization. No data will be lost. However, from Redis point of view, if the link is down, traffic between master and slave is lost. That's why a full synchronization or a partial synchronization is needed.